# Apex not accepting 0x00000000

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

In Java I can write the following statement:

```java
Integer data = 0x00000000;
```

But in Apex the same line of code gives me the following error:

> Error: Compile Error: expecting a semi-colon, found 'x00000000'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Apex Code does not allow hexadecimal integer literals. `Integer data = 0;` should accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: That's really bad, I have a whole code expressed in hexadecimal integers, that means I need to convert them one by one.